# Custom Func<> delegate inside Linq where clause

Tags: c#, linq, func

I should customize a Func expression so that I should make a check of an array of bytes inside of it a return true if are this array is equal to a field in a POCO..

So I don't know how to define it...

```
public Patient GetPatientByIdentificationCode(byte[] bytes)
    {
        return DbSet.Where(Func<>).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

the Patient has an IdentificationCode that is an arrya of bytes...

thanks

Comment: What is a type of `DbSet` items? Considering its items type is `TSource` delegate should be of type `Func<TSource, Boolean>`

Comment: So why the -1?... DbSet is a class of EF: Represents an entity set that is used to perform create, read, update, and delete operations. A non-generic version of DbSet<TEntity> which can be used when the type of entity is not known at build time...should had i to explain that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the order of the bytes is part of the equality then you can use [`SequenceEqual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342073.aspx):

```
return DbSet.Where(p => p.IdentificationCode.SequenceEqual(bytes)).FirstOrDefault();
```

If order doesn't matter then you can check that the elements are the same and the lengths are the same:

```
return DbSet.Where(p => 
                 p.IdentificationCode.Length == bytes.Length && 
                 p.IdentificationCode.Intersect(bytes).Count() == p.IdentificationCode.Length)
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

It will likely be slower than `SequenceEqual` so only use it if the order of the bytes isn't important.

As a side note I would STRONGLY suggest making this either a real method or extension method on `Patient` as I suspect you'll be using it A LOT.

Either that, or change to a more easily comparable (and displayable) type than an array of bytes.

Answer (score 1):

In principle something like this should work:

```
return DbSet
  .Where(i => i.IdentificationCode.Length == bytes.Length)
  .FirstOrDefault();
```

If you could be more clear then we could maybe be more helpful. Specifically you could tell use if `DbSet` is a collection of `Patient` or not.

Comment: Sorry, yes it is a collection of Patient... But I should check if the array have the same bytes, not the same length..The question, although, is also more general: how can i define a Func<..> variable that I can reuse from inside the Where clause?... thank you